# Tomcat 8.0 Rewrite Valve

Tags: tomcat

I am trying to use the RewriteValve in Tomcat 8.0 http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/rewrite.html

In $CATALINA_HOME/conf/server.xml, I added

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve" />
```

right below the Host tag

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
```

Created a `rewrite.config` in the `$CATALINA_HOME/conf` directory with the following

```
RewriteRule ^/abc /myapp
```

where `http:/host:port/myapp` is a working webapp.

So now when I go to `http://host:port/abc` I expect to be redirected to `http://host:port/myapp` but I get a 404 `the requested resource is not available` instead.

It doesn't look like it is even reading my rewrite.config file. The access log in the logs directory just reports the `"GET /abc HTTP/1.1" 404 1000` with no further details.

What am I missing? Thanks

Comment: Have you enabled DEBUG logging for `RewriteValve`? Anything relevant in the logs? At first glance, what you have looks correct. What version of Apache Tomcat are you using?

Comment: How can I enable DEBUG logging for `RewriteValve`? I am using Tomcat 8.0.15

Comment: Chris - Any ideas, what else can I try? I am just about at my wits end, not sure how to debug/troubleshoot this further. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Read the Tomcat users' guide section on logging to see how to configure `DEBUG` logging for a single class. You basically just add a line to `logging.properites` which configures Java's logging mechanism (`java.util.log`).

Comment: I did that already. I added a line to $CATALINA_HOME/conf/logging.properties `org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve.level = FINE` but that didn't appear to do anything, no entries in any of the log files in /logs.

Comment: Chris - Any ideas? I went back to using the URLRewriteFilter at http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/ but since this is now built into Tomcat, I would really like to use it instead of yet another third party component.

Comment: Oh, unfortunately, the `RewriteValve` doesn't use its own (class-specific) logger. Instead, it logs to its container's valve. So if you have your `<Valve>` configured to be a child of the `<Host>`, then you need to change the log level on the host (like this: `org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].level = DEBUG`).

Comment: OK now we are getting somewhere. DEBUG didn't work. I added `org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].level = FINE` to the conf/logging.properties and saw `19-Nov-2014 13:30:21.322 FINE [Catalina-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve.startInternal No configuration resource found: Catalina/localhost/rewrite.config in ...` in localhost.2014-11-19.log. So I moved my rewrite.config file from /conf to conf/Catalina/localhost and now it is picking up my rewrite rules. Maybe the documentation can make this clearer. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I've noticed a lot of room for improvement with the documentation. The `RewriteValve` is a new feature without a lot of mileage under its belt, so this is good feedback.

Answer (score 15):

In Tomcat documentation http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/rewrite.html is written

> The rewrite valve can be configured as a valve added in a Host. See virtual-server documentation for informations how to configure it. It will use a rewrite.config file containing the rewrite directives, it must be placed in the Host configuration folder.

so try to move `rewrite.config` into `$CATALINA_HOME/conf/Catalina/localhost`
Small hint: you can misspell something in `rewrite.config` ( e.g. `xxRewriteRule` ) and then if tomcat reads this file it fails. I think in your case tomcat starts even if you misspell something (because it is not read).

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like something different than the default path `$CATALINA_HOME/conf/Catalina/localhost`, you might be able to make use of the [*resourcePath*](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/valves/rewrite/RewriteValve.html#resourcePath) field in your [RewriteValve](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/valves/rewrite/RewriteValve.html) xml definition to specify a relative path to the configuration file. (Admittedly, I have not used this.)

Alternatively, you can add the valve to `$CATALINA_HOME/conf/context.xml` and then move `rewrite.config` into your web application's WEB-INF folder.

From the [documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/rewrite.html#Configuration):

> It can also be in the context.xml of a webapp. The valve will then use a rewrite.config file containing the rewrite directives, it must be placed in the WEB-INF folder of the web application

Comment: The resourcePath field setup doesn't work. It is not a recognized property when trying to set it. Also, you can define the valve in $CATALINA_BASE/conf/[engine]/[hostname]/your_app.xml and put the rewrite.config in the WEB-INF directory of the application (your_app).

Comment: @Achille this does not seem to work for me either, on 8.0.53. No output from `RewriteValve` at all.

Answer (score 0):

I had to comment out the AccessLogValve in the server.xml for my rewrite valve to work

Answer (score -4):

According to [apacheDoc](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/rewrite.html)

The rewrite valve is configured as a valve using the org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve class name.

The rewrite valve can be configured as a valve added in a Host. See virtual-server documentation for informations how to configure it. It will use a rewrite.config file containing the rewrite directives, it must be placed in the Host configuration folder.

It can also be in the context.xml of a webapp. The valve will then use a rewrite.config file containing the rewrite directives, it must be placed in the WEB-INF folder of the web application