# Using Tomcat's Rewrite Valve

Tags: apache, tomcat, url-rewriting, tomcat-valve

I am trying to use Tomcat's rewrite valve to rewrite a URL to not show the actually WebApp name.

The current URL looks like http://example.com/Thingstuff.  I would still like the URL to point to the Thingstuff app, but I would like users to see http://example.com/DifferentStuff.

I have not found a comprehensible solution on google yet, so I appreciate any help I can get here.

Thank you,
Brandon

Answer (score 0):

You can configure RewriteRule as below

RewriteRule /DifferentStuff /Thingstuff [R,NE]

For more details, refer [Tomcat Rewrite Valve](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/rewrite.html)

If you are doing this for the first time, there is a good possibility that your server is not configured properly to read `rewrite.config`

The below SO post will help you verify and correct that.

[Tomcat 8.0 Rewrite Valve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26932253/tomcat-8-0-rewrite-valve)