# Tomcat 9 Configure 301 redirect for subdomain to domain

Tags: tomcat, url-rewriting, http-status-code-301, tomcat9

How can I make a 301 redirect with tomcat from the www subdomain to the root domain.

I tried the following without any success, the www subdomain is still displaying. I may be missing something but I cant figure out what is missing.

For our project built in liferay 7 community which is a multi tenant with only a tomcat server (no apache or nginx in front), I need to redirect the URLs accessed with the www subdomain to the root domain.

I am trying the [rewrite valve](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/rewrite.html) but i cant figure out how and where to write it in the server.xml

My best trial:
in the server.xml

```
    <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
        <!-- Added valve -->    
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve"/>
      </Host>
```

I added the last valve.

In the WEB-INF i created a file: rewrite.config to which i added:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST}  ^www.*$
RewriteRule ^www.*   %{REMOTE_HOST}  [L]
```

The redirection i need is a 301 for the www subdomain only and not for URI.

The above test did not work as I can still access the www subdomain.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tomcat 8.0 Rewrite Valve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26932253/tomcat-8-0-rewrite-valve)

Comment: @Selaron its not a duplicate as I am trying to redirect the subdomain and not the URI and the resource indicated in the answer is the same resource i am trying to use

Comment: Please describe the difference between expected and observed behavior as your question is missing an actual question.

Comment: @Selaron I updated the question with what I need to achieve

Comment: Much clearer now - so you want to redirect from `http://www.example.com` to `http://example.com` using status code 301 (permanently moved) ? Did you place the `rewrite.config` into the `WEB-INF` of your web application? Using a trivial rewrite rule, can you verify or debug that the RewriteValve is considering that configuration file at all? For example by rewriting a request to `/welcome.html` to `/notYouAgain.html`.