# How do I get my tomcat server to print debug messages about the rewrite Valve?

Tags: logging, mod-rewrite, tomcat9

I'm making use of the rewrite valve in Tomcat, but something isn't working right. I want to get debugging messages in my catalina log file so I can figure out the issue, but I'm not sure how.

In my logging.properties I just tried putting a blanket

```
.level = FINE
```

But this obvously made my catalina log too verbose. I did see what I was after though, which was these lines:

```
20-Feb-2020 13:42:34.061 FINE [main] org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve.parse Add rule with pattern ^/?(.*) and substitution https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1
20-Feb-2020 13:42:34.061 FINE [main] org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve.parse Add condition =80 test %{SERVER_PORT} to rule with pattern ^/?(.*) and substitution https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1
```

What do I need to put in my logging.propeties so I'm only focusing on RewriteValve messages?

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution for the original question.

As mentioned in [Tomcat 8.0 Rewrite Valve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26932253/tomcat-8-0-rewrite-valve#comment42572583_26932253), `org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve` has no own logger.

The RewriteValve logging can be activated in Tomcats `logging.properties` by:

```
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].level = FINE
```

If you run Tomcat within Eclipse, add the following vm start argument to the Tomcat launch settings:

```
 -Djava.util.logging.config.file="path/to/logging.properties"
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `.level = FINE` with
`org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve=FINE`

The prefix of log lines and the left side of the properties entry are used by the logger to decide what to log.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Neither `org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve.level=FINE`
nor `org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve=FINE`